# Scrapy returns only the first product for each page

Tags: python, scrapy

I try to learn Scrapy but I am stuck for 3 days with a problem, maybe some of you could help me with a solution or a suggestion.
I try to extract all the products from one category of a site, and for each product, I want only 3 categories: 2 from the main page when all the products are set, and 1 category from the details of the product(this is the cod of the product); and for this, I have accessed the link of each product.
All extracted products go to ItemLoader.
In the Items file, I have used the MapComposer and TakeFirst processor for all the items.

The problem is that my code extracts only the first product from each page.

This is the code:

```
import os
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from ..items import CutotulItem


class CutotulSpiderLoader(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cutotul_spider_loader'
    start_urls = ['https://cutotul.ro/39-karcher-aspiratoare-profesionale']

    def __init__(self):
        self.model = ""

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://cutotul.ro/39-karcher-aspiratoare-profesionale', callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.css("div.columns-container")
        for product in products:
            # get details link
            details_link = product.xpath("//a[@class='lnk_view btn btn-default']/@href").get()

            # get details
            yield response.follow(url=details_link, callback=self.parse_details)
            product_name_xpath = "//span[@class='grid-name']/text()"
            product_price_xpath = "//span[@class='price product-price']/text()"
            product_model_xpath = "".join(self.model)

            # loader
            loader = ItemLoader(item=CutotulItem(), selector=product, response=response)
            loader.add_xpath("product_name", product_name_xpath)
            loader.add_xpath("product_price", product_price_xpath)
            loader.add_value("product_model", product_model_xpath)
            yield loader.load_item()

        # nav to next page
        # Get the next response for x items from the next page - persist until no more #

        next_page = response.xpath("//li[@class='pagination_next']//@href").get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_details(self, response):
        # set variable to response for model
        self.model = response.css("span[itemprop='sku']").css("::text").get()
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use relative xpath for each product (eg `.//a` instead of `//a`).
2. You aren't looping over the items, `products` is just the container of those items.
3. `parse_details` won't work - scrapy is asynchronous so it won't wait for `self.model` to update and you'll get an empty string. I fixed it as an example but you can fixed it however you want.
4. What's left for you to do is to check if the pagination works (I didn't check it), and fix (if you want) the price's format.

```py
import os
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
# from ..items import CutotulItem


class CutotulItem(scrapy.Item):
    product_name = scrapy.Field()
    product_price = scrapy.Field()
    product_model = scrapy.Field()


class CutotulSpiderLoader(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cutotul_spider_loader'
    start_urls = ['https://cutotul.ro/39-karcher-aspiratoare-profesionale']

    def __init__(self):
        self.model = ""

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://cutotul.ro/39-karcher-aspiratoare-profesionale', callback=self.parse)

    async def parse(self, response):
        # products = response.css("div.columns-container")
        products = response.css('div.product-container')
        for product in products:
            # get details link
            details_link = product.xpath(".//a[@class='lnk_view btn btn-default']/@href").get()

            # get details
            # yield response.follow(url=details_link, callback=self.parse_details)
            req = response.follow(url=details_link)
            resp = await self.crawler.engine.download(req, self)
            self.model = resp.css("span[itemprop='sku']").css("::text").get()

            product_name_xpath = ".//span[@class='grid-name']/text()"
            product_price_xpath = ".//span[@class='price product-price']/text()"
            product_model_xpath = "".join(self.model)

            # loader
            loader = ItemLoader(item=CutotulItem(), selector=product, response=response)
            loader.add_xpath("product_name", product_name_xpath)
            loader.add_xpath("product_price", product_price_xpath)
            loader.add_value("product_model", product_model_xpath)
            yield loader.load_item()

        # nav to next page
        # Get the next response for x items from the next page - persist until no more #

        next_page = response.xpath("//li[@class='pagination_next']//@href").get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_details(self, response):
        # set variable to response for model
        self.model = response.css("span[itemprop='sku']").css("::text").get()
```